# Absolute imports from "tests" package fails with ModuleNotFoundError in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ipython, python-module

Given the following simple Python project,

```
$ tree
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── src
└── tests
    ├── test_foo.py
    └── util.py

$ cat Pipfile
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
ipython = "*"
pytest = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

$ cat tests/util.py 
FOO = 5

$ cat tests/test_foo.py 
from tests.util import FOO


def test_foo():
    assert FOO == 5
```

Running the PyCharm debugger on `test_foo` using `pytest` with the appropriate `pipenv --venv` produces the following error:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.8194.15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.util'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `test_foo.py`, if you print out the `sys.path`, you'll notice that PyCharm has injected `<path_to_venv>/lib/python<version>/site-packages/IPython/extensions` which happens to contain a `tests` module that clobbers the local namespace `tests`. This issue has already been reported upstream: see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11592.

There are two workarounds for now:

1. Rename your `tests` directory to something else.
2. Remove the `<path_to_venv>/lib/python<version>/site-packages/IPython/extensions/tests` folder.